# R: Loop Over Values in a List

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like my loop to use calculated value as the index but it seems it wont allow me to do so.

Here's a sample code:

```
stype_rep <- c(6:10,11:15,31:35)

rep <- 6 #this can change


for (rep in stype_rep){

  print(sprintf("rep start loop: %s",rep))
  rep <- rep + 6 #this can change
  print(sprintf("rep added: %s", rep))

}
```

When you run the code, it is not using the new value of `rep` which is `rep + 6`.
How do I do that?

Dixi

Comment: You're overwriting the `rep` variable in `for (rep in stype_rep)`.

Comment: `stype_rep` and `rep` are inputs, what is your expected output? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I would like the iterator to jump to a certain value. For example, from rep=6, I wanted it to jump to rep=12 which is rep=rep+6. This rep=12 is have the index 7 in the stype object.

Comment: you need to use the `next` loop control statement.

Comment: The instructions `rep <- 6` and `for (rep in stype_rep)` are self contradictory. And so are `for (rep in stype_rep)` and `rep <- rep+6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change `vector` recursively outside `for` loop you need to use indexing. Please see the code below:

```
rep <- c(6:10, 11:15, 31:35)

for (i in seq_along(rep)[-1] - 1){
  print(sprintf("rep start loop: %s",rep[i]))
  rep[i + 1] <- rep[i] + 6 #this can change
  print(sprintf("rep added: %s",rep[i]))
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "rep start loop: 6"
[1] "rep added: 6"
[1] "rep start loop: 12"
[1] "rep added: 12"
[1] "rep start loop: 18"
[1] "rep added: 18"
[1] "rep start loop: 24"
[1] "rep added: 24"
[1] "rep start loop: 30"
[1] "rep added: 30"
[1] "rep start loop: 36"
```